# Postgres Error: could not read block 167593 in file... SQL state: XX001

Tags: postgresql, corruption

When creating a new column on a table, I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR: could not read block 167593 in file "pg_tblspc/16384/PG_9.4_201409291/16386/157223695.1": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
SQL state: XX001
```

Obviously not good, as SQL state XX001 means corrupt data. I'm not too bothered as this is not critical data and can relatively easily be re-loaded from the source.

However, after searching for similar issues, all I can see from other people is this error for 'of relation base', not 'in file'. How is 'in file' different, and what does this mean? Is it more likely that I have a hardware issue?

Also, how can I check to see for certain that the data is corrupted?

Answer (score 2):

> However, after searching for similar issues, all I can see from other
>   people is this error for 'of relation base', not 'in file'. How is 'in
>   file' different, and what does this mean? Is it more likely that I
>   have a hardware issue?

No, it's the same issue. The error message used to refer to the relation in older versions of PostgreSQL, but it was changed at some point (version `9.0`, probably) to refer to the corresponding file instead.

I think the switch to the new message format happened [here](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=23dc89d2c385e8e362cb4b8186b4d4ad02242ac0):

> commit 23dc89d2c385e8e362cb4b8186b4d4ad02242ac0
>   Author: Heikki Linnakangas 
>   Date:   Wed Aug 5 18:01:54 2009 +0000
>
> ```
> Improve error messages in md.c. When a filesystem operation like open() or
> fsync() fails, say "file" rather than "relation" when printing the filename.
>
> This makes messages that display block numbers a bit confusing. For example,
> in message 'could not read block 150000 of file "base/1234/5678.1"', 150000
> is the block number from the beginning of the relation, ie. segment 0, not
> 150000th block within that segment. Per discussion, users aren't usually
> interested in the exact location within the file, so we can live with that.
>
> To ease constructing error messages, add FilePathName(File) function to
> return the pathname of a virtual fd.
> ```

Comment: Useful & interesting info, thanks @Daniel